# Buscador Collapsible

Tags: javascript, css

Estoy tratando de hacer un buscador que sea desplegable y contraíble al mismo tiempo y que haga un cambio entre dos fuentes de Fontawesome.

No logro hacer lo que quiero y no sé como hacerlo. Entiendo que es con Javascript pero no se Javascript.

Hasta el momento logré que se desplegue hacia la izquierda pero la lupa no se desplaza dentro del buscador que es lo que yo quiero lograr y que cuando esté activo entonces que en su lugar aparezca un fa-times que después lo cierre...

Otra cosa que no logro sacar es el recuadro del input al momento de escribir... No encuentro la forma.

Les dejo todo lo que tengo:

```
  <div class="search-content">
    <form>
      <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <input type="search" id="cl-serch" placeholder="Buscar" />
    </form>
  </div>

  body { 
  display: flex; 
  height: 100%; 
  margin: auto; 
  padding: 0; 
  text-align: center; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  width: 100%; 
  }

  .search-content { 
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: 500px; 
  margin: 20px auto; 
  padding: 0px; 
  }

 .search-content input[type='search'] { 
  border: 0.5px solid #000; 
  padding-left: 12px; 
  width: 55%; 
  display: inline-block; 
  padding: 15px;     
  height: 60px;
  float: right; 
  }

 .search-content a { 
  text-decoration: none; 
  margin-left: 15px; 
  font-size: 16px; 
  }

  .search-content form { 
  width: 100%; 
  }

  .search-content input[type='search']:after { 
  transition-delay: 3s; 
  transform: scaleX(200ms); 
  width: 55%; 
  }

  .search-content input[type='search']:hover, 
  .search-content input[type='search']:focus { 
  border: 0.5 solid #000; 
  }

  .search-content .btn { 
  padding: 20px; 
  color: #000; 
  background-color: transparent; 
  border: transparent; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  display: inline-block; 
  float: right; 
  margin: 0px; 
  box-sizing: none; 
  }

 .btn.focus, 
 .btn:focus {
 outline: 0;
 box-shadow: none;
 }

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn").on( "click", function() {
$("#cl-serch").animate({width: 'toggle'}, "1000")
});
});
```

Me podrían ayudar?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No alcance a hacerlo con Fontawesome, pero puedes intentar algo asi. Me cuentas.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").on("click", function() {
      $("#cl-serch").animate({
        width: 'toggle'
      }, "1000");
      $(".search-content_item").toggleClass("active");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.search-content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

.search-content input[type='search'] {
  padding-left: 12px;
  width: 55%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 60px;
  float: right;
}

.search-content a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.search-content form {
  width: 100%;
}

.search-content input[type='search']:after {
  transition-delay: 3s;
  transform: scaleX(200ms);
  width: 55%;
}

.search-content .btn {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: none;
}

.btn.focus,
.btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

input {
  border: none;
}

input:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.search-content_item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 60px;
  width: auto;
}

.search-content_item.active a::before {
  content: "";
}

.search-content_item a::before {
  content: "×";
}

.search-content_item a {
  position: relative;
}

.search-content_item a i,
svg {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js'></script>
<div class="search-content">
  <form>
    <div class="search-content_item active">
      <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <input type="search" id="cl-serch" placeholder="Buscar">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```